# Can use the synchronized method lead to degrade performance in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the legacy code which uses the `synchronized` many times in the codes.
I found that the app do not have the multi threaded so I think that removing the synchronized will be fine.

In such scenario, can I expect that the execution time will be better by removing it?

I think that using synchronized can degrade performance when it comes to using multi threaded. But in my case, it is a single thread but uses it in my legacy code. So I will remove it. Then will the performance be better?

Look forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: Maybe but in most cases won't. You should measure to find out what's the reason of your performance issues. However, I think if it is a single-threaded application, synchronization cannot have such an impact on performance.

Comment: As you already noted synchronization will mostly affect multi-threaded applications trying to access the same synchronized sections and waiting for them to be released. In a single-threaded application this wouldn't be the case so just removing synchronization shouldn't improve performance noticeably. In general, algorithms and bad design have greater negative impact on performance than low level constructs like synchronization so you should use a profiler/sampler to check where your application is spending its time.

Comment: @sclee1 in recent java versions that definitely may cause severe performance issues: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75324470/3426309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but performance improvement may be limited if your application is low throughout, which might not have a big difference.

Let us demonstrate with a simple example:

```java
public class Test1 {

    @Test
    public void demo() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            long l1 = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                add1();
            }
            System.out.println("\nCost add1(" + j + "): " + (System.nanoTime() - l1));

            long l2 = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                add2();
            }
            System.out.println("Cost add2(" + j + "): " + (System.nanoTime() - l2));
        }
    }

    private int count1, count2;

    public void add1() {
        count1++;
    }

    public synchronized void add2() {
        count2++;
    }
}
```

The execution result on the blow shows that even when the loop is repeated a million times, the difference is less than 20 milliseconds. So if your task is simple, it will improve performance, but it's limited.

BTW, the result time unit is nanoseconds, and 1 millisecond = 1*10^6 nanoseconds.

```
Cost add1(0): 4172100
Cost add2(0): 18674600

Cost add1(1): 272000
Cost add2(1): 19282100

Cost add1(2): 2018000
Cost add2(2): 19526700

Cost add1(3): 2482300
Cost add2(3): 19588300

Cost add1(4): 1684900
Cost add2(4): 18640000

Cost add1(5): 1673600
Cost add2(5): 19613800

Cost add1(6): 1695100
Cost add2(6): 20073500

Cost add1(7): 1687300
Cost add2(7): 18830400

Cost add1(8): 1642500
Cost add2(8): 19282500

Cost add1(9): 1693700
Cost add2(9): 18667900
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Javadoc on Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) :

> When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns. The lock release occurs even if the return was caused by an uncaught exception.

So, for your single threaded program, if you remove `synchronized`, that can improve the performance, maybe not by that much, but **Yes, it will.** Without the `synchronized` keyword, the **overhead for locking and releasing the resources** won't be there anymore. If there is many methods that are `synchronized`, then the overhead can be in higher side.